# How should I move a record between tables using Peewee?

Tags: python, peewee

I have two tables with identical fields. One is for active users and one is for archived users:

```
 class BaseClass(Model)
      class Meta:
           database = db

 class User(BaseClass):
      name = CharField()
      # Various other fields

 class UserArchive(BaseClass):
      name = CharField()
      # Identical fields to User
```

Users are added like this:

```
 User.create(name = "Tim")
```

But when I need to move a user from User to UserArchive, I do something like this:

```
 user = User.get(User.name == "Tim")
 user_data = user._data
 del user_data["id"]
 UserArchive.create(**user_data)
 user.delete_instance()
```

This feels a bit cumbersome. Is there a recommended way to move a record from one table to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UserArchive.insert_from(
   query=User.select(User.name).where(User.active == False),
   columns=[UserArchive.name])
```

Generates

```
INSERT INTO userarchive ("name") SELECT "name" FROM user WHERE "active" = false;
```

Provide your own where clause to suit your needs. You'll still need to delete the User row of course.